# triad practice tips?

Tags: chords, practice, intervals

I am having a hard time practicing triads.

Just figuring out 3rd or 5th of a given note, or 4th(from 5th down to 1st) of a given note takes really long time.

Is there a good way to speeding up figuring out desired notes?

Comment: What instrument do you play? Do you want to practice spelling triads note for note or play triads as chords? Your question lacks details that are important.

Answer (score 1):

Practicing cadences in all the major and minor keys is a well known fundamental to practice.

An example in `C` major would be `ii6 V I`, or spelling the chords from lowest to highest, `F A D` to `D G B` to `E G C`, which would be played over a bass of `F G C`. Patterns like that can be rotated through three positions where each of the three triad tones will be placed in the top (highest pitch)  position.

Practicing cadences in that way exposes you to all the most important tonal triads, all of the "inversions" of the triads, and covers common voice leading.

Many harmony textbooks will provide exercises for playing cadences so you can see the common patterns.

> Is there a good way to speeding up figuring out desired notes?

At this beginning stage, I think you want to focus on *playing patterns* or cadences and one-octave scales, which will train your hands to move through a key either by steps (scales and scale fragments) and movement by thirds (skipping every other scale step) which is the spacing for chords, triads and seventh chords.

Part of that training doesn't require you think through every single pitch letter you play. A big part of the practice to train your hand movements to become smooth and easy. The some portion of your practice can focus on stuff like naming pitch letters, intervals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Just figuring out 3rd or 5th of a given note, or 4th(from 5th down to 1st) of a given note takes really long time.
>
> Is there a good way to speeding up figuring out desired notes?

Practice more, it will get faster. When your muscles work, your brain learns. So put your muscles to work, and keep working. If you are asking for a way to learn without working, then unfortunately that's not possible. No pain, no gain.

Practice different ways of producing the triads:

- (1) **list** the note names like C-E-G,
- (2) **play** the triads on your instrument,
- (3) **write** the triads in staff notation,
- (4) **sing** the note names.

Do all of these exercises (list, play, write, sing) in different variations.

- (A) in different keys, like D major with two sharps (notice that the letter names are the same, just some of them have sharps)
- (B) in ascending order, one by one for all diatonic triads, like in D major: D-F#-A, E-G-B, F#-A-C#, G-B-D, ...
- (C) in descending order, like in Eb major: Eb-G-Bb, D-F-Ab, C-Eb-G, Bb-D-F, ...
- (D) in steps of thirds like C-E-G, E-G-B, G-B-D, B-D-F, D-F-A, F-A-C, A-C-E
- (E) the same but first inversions (E-G-C)
- (F) the same but second inversions (G-C-E)
- (G) take a song lead sheet with chord symbols and list/play/write/sing the triads specified by the chord symbols

After you've done this an hour a day for a few weeks, report back if it's got easier.

Answer (score 0):

Basing your question on the piano - guitar is the other instrument that can play triads - but is far more complex as the same note is found in differing places.

Knowing your scales is the key here. Particularly the first five notes thereof

The basic triad in root position is ^1 ^3 and ^5. Fairly straightforward. So, staring on whatever note you choose,(let's say C), and making that the root, the other two members of the triad will be E and G. Every time. Play the root, miss ^2, play^3, miss ^4 and play ^5. That works for both major and minor triads, working from the respective scales.

You will notice a similar pattern, fingering-wise, for them all, to make life easier. Every one can be played using three fingers from one hand.

Once you have all of these under your belt, you'll be aware of what the notes actually are, or at least where they are on the keyboard. From that, it's a simple substitution move to slide your whole hand downwards, so the note that was lowest is now the note in the middle - it's called the 2nd inversion.

While you're doing hall that, it's fun to play up and down through the whole piano, using the pedal if you like, single and both hands. It sound like you know what you're doing! And it'll embed the notes of those triads in a satisfying way, too.